# How can I programatically add a user to subversion from a shell script?

Tags: svn, shell

I would like to create a subversion user without restarting the subversion server but the only way to do this seems to be to edit the passwd file.

Is there a command to add a user?

Comment: Is there a command to add a user?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to authenticate depending on how svn is accessed. If you're serving it through apache htpasswd or htdigest may do what you want.

Comment: Is there a way to add users when just a svnserve daemon is running?

Comment: Also htpasswd requires that the subversion server is restarted

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the svnserve daemon only, then the user file is the file named in

```
password-db = passwd.conf
```

in the `conf/svnserve.conf` configuration file under the `[general]` header.
There is no API to add users to this file but you can always do:

```
echo "$user = $passwd" >> conf/passwd.conf
```

Which will simply append the new user at the end of the list (I assume you have the `[users]` header already set at the top of that file.

I don't think you should restart the server for the new user to be taken into account.